# How to debug android /system/bin/linker in gcc?

Tags: android, debugging, linker, gdb

in emulator-arm.exe.
After setting up symbols and sources and stepping into dlopen() I only got nothing but

```
warning: (Internal error: pc 0xb6f576e4 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
```

I could't stop at the function or see a line of code.

Comment: That warning can be safely ignored. What is your *real* problem?

Comment: @Employed Russian Sorry I didn't explain it well. The real problem is I got nothing else. I could't stop at the function or see a line of code.